# Sagemaker not outputting Tensorboard logs to S3 during training

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, tensorboard, amazon-sagemaker

I'm training a model with Tensorflow using Amazon Sagemaker, and I'd like to be able to monitor training progress while the job is running. During training however, no Tensorboard files are output to S3, only once the training job is completed are the files uploaded to S3. After training has completed, I can download the files and see that Tensorboard has been logging values correctly throughout training, despite only being updated in S3 once after training completes.

I'd like to know why Sagemaker isn't uploading the Tensorboard information to S3 throughout the training process?

Here is the code from my notebook on Sagemaker that kicks off the training job

```
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow
from sagemaker.debugger import DebuggerHookConfig, CollectionConfig, TensorBoardOutputConfig

import time

bucket = 'my-bucket'
output_prefix = 'training-jobs'
model_name = 'my-model'
dataset_name = 'my-dataset'
dataset_path = f's3://{bucket}/datasets/{dataset_name}'

output_path = f's3://{bucket}/{output_prefix}'
job_name = f'{model_name}-{dataset_name}-training-{time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", time.gmtime())}'
s3_checkpoint_path = f"{output_path}/{job_name}/checkpoints" # Checkpoints are updated live as expected
s3_tensorboard_path = f"{output_path}/{job_name}/tensorboard" # Tensorboard data isn't appearing here until the training job has completed

tensorboard_output_config = TensorBoardOutputConfig(
    s3_output_path=s3_tensorboard_path,
    container_local_output_path= '/opt/ml/output/tensorboard' # I have confirmed this is the unaltered path being provided to tf.summary.create_file_writer()
)

role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()

estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='main.py', source_dir='./', role=role, max_run=60*60*24*5,
                           output_path=output_path,
                           checkpoint_s3_uri=s3_checkpoint_path,
                           tensorboard_output_config=tensorboard_output_config,
                           instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.g4dn.xlarge',
                           framework_version='2.3.1', py_version='py37', script_mode=True)

dpe_estimator.fit({'train': dataset_path}, wait=True, job_name=job_name)
```

Comment: take a look at the cloudwatch logs for the training job.. is there anything relevant there ?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be. No results yielded by a search for "tensorboard" in the logs.
The only remotely related logs appear to be `Creating hook from json_config at /opt/ml/input/config/debughookconfig.json.` and  `Saving to /opt/ml/output/tensors` , which appear before training starts.

Comment: Just to confirm.. when the training job has completed, are the logs uploaded to the exact same s3 location where you are trying to upload during the training ? Or it is a different bucket?

Comment: The logs are uploaded to a directory nested within the location I'm trying to have them uploaded throughout training, which I'm passing as the `s3_output_path`. 
The directory I pass to the `TensorBoardOutputConfig` is `s3://{bucket}/training-jobs/{job_name}/tensorboard`. 
At the end of training, the logs output file to a directory nested within that, specifically `s3://{bucket}/training-jobs/{job_name}/tensorboard/{job_name}/tensorboard_output/`

Comment: Update: I've changed `s3_output_path` to just `s3://{bucket}/training-jobs` so that after training, the logs are directly in `s3://{bucket}/training-jobs/{job_name}/tensorboard-output/` and not nested, but the `tensorboard-output` folder and logs still don't appear until training completes

Comment: It's weird.. could it be a permission issue on the s3 bucket ? I always used bucket with "sagemaker" in the name to have permissions set automatically.. could it be the reason ?

Comment: I just created a new bucket prefixed with 'sagemaker', created a new notebook instance that accesses the dataset and outputs to that bucket, but it's still not live updating.

Comment: Looking here https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/amazon_sagemaker_debugger.html#capture-real-time-tensorboard-data-from-the-debugging-hook you are doing it right.. maybe a bug in sagemaker? I can only suggest to carefully read line by line the cloudwatch log, must be something there..

Comment: Alright, I'll do some more reading and testing and see what I can find. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ChrisB have you found something, or any other hint? I schedule job on AWS by create-training-job , and my tensorboard logs are filled on S3 only after the training is finished. I see that the 'empty' tensorboard files are there during training so this is not a problem with permissions. I as well tried to configure my tensorboard to directly write to s3, but this ended up with nothing in S3 and nothing in logs.

Comment: I haven't, unfortunately. I've had to move onto other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44564) on tensorflow github related to the s3 client in version 2.3.1 which is the one you are using. Check in the cloudwatch logs if you have an error like

> OP_REQUIRES failed at whole_file_read_ops.cc:116 : Failed precondition: AWS Credentials have not been set properly. Unable to access the specified S3 location

Then the provided solution is to add `GetObejectVersion` permission to the bucket. Alternatively, to confirm that is a tensorflow issue, you can try a different version.

Comment: After looking through the logs, I can't find anything related to S3 permissions

Comment: I tried updating the role permissions to include `GetObjectVersion` just incase, but the tensorboard logs still don't appear in S3 until after training completes

Comment: can you try a version of tensorflow < 2.3.1?

Answer (score 0):

First some speculation without any facts: Sagemaker could work as some other systems that sync files between local drive and s3. They might check that the file hasn't been accessed recently before syncing it so that they don't copy it while someone is writing to it. The log files are written constantly until shutdown so that might result in them not being copied ever.

I have used Sagemaker Docker containers with same problem. I've tried two ways circumvent this problem and they seemed to work.

First one is to periodically create a new log file. So e.g. every 30 minutes call again `tf.summary.create_file_writer(...)` to switch to a new log file. Old file is synced to s3 when it's not used anymore.

Second one is to directly write logs to s3. `tf.summary.create_file_writer('s3://bucket/dir/')`. This is more instant way of getting the info into s3.